# How can I add horizontal error bar in Excel 2010 or 2013?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[No horizontal error bar can be selected in line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtMSV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your graph needs to be a `Scatter` plot to have horizontal error bars. You cannot have horizontal error bars with a `Line` plot.